# get data attribute of a bootstrap modal link

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, custom-data-attribute

I saw a lot of subject but I still dont have my answer.

**Situation :** I have a link which open a modal popin

```
<a class="pointer" data-filtre='non' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalAnnexeDe" >
<a class="pointer" data-filtre="oui" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalAnnexeDe" >
```

and i have my js

```
$('#myModalAnnexeDe').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
     var filtre=$(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-filtre');
     alert($(event.relatedTarget).attr("data-filtre"));
     if(filtre == 'oui'){
         $('.notform').hide();
     }
});
```

**result** of the alert is 'undefined'

I also try :

```
$(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-filtre')
$(event.relatedTarget).data('filtre')
$(event.relatedTarget).data($('a'),'filtre')
$(event.relatedTarget).data(a,'filtre')
$(event.relatedTarget).attr(filtre)
$(event.relatedTarget).attr('filtre')
$(event.relatedTarget).dataset.filtre
$(this).attr("data-filtre")
...
```

And maybe many others...

*about show.bs.modal & event.relatedTarget  from bootstrap doc :*

> **show.bs.modal**     This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is
>   available as the relatedTarget property of the event.

thanks in advance.

Comment: still the same : alert($(this).attr("data-filtre")); => undefined 
alert($this); gave me a js object.

Comment: I don't feel there is any error in the code you showed above. Please have look to this https://jsfiddle.net/ZcLSE/1619/

Comment: @Vincent , you could use simple JavaScript method to get attribute value... e.relatedTarget.getAttribute('data-filtre') ... It will give you the value.

Answer (score 6):

It works just fine with your code only. check your jQuery Version compatibility with bootstrap version first.

And for the reference purpose I have also provided working code with a simple changes in your code like tag completion and added bootstrap modal and jquery link.

```js
$('#myModalAnnexeDe').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
     var filtre=$(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-filtre');
     alert($(event.relatedTarget).attr("data-filtre"));
     if(filtre == 'oui'){
         $('.notform').hide();
     }
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="pointer" data-filtre='non' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalAnnexeDe">non</a>
<a class="pointer" data-filtre="oui" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalAnnexeDe">oui</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModalAnnexeDe" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried again a lot of thing and still didn't work with the show.bs.modal event.

So I just did

```
$('.lienfiltre').on('click', function (){
  if($(this).attr('data-filtre') === 'oui'){
     $('.notform').hide();
  }
});
```

and here it's working. 
ty